# AWS API Gateway: New Stage not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created my DEV environment without any problem. It's work Fine.

but I'm trying to create a QA environment (or any other) and it does not work.

the only difference between the two environments is the variable that refers to the backend (I have tried putting the same one and the problem persists)

if I try some method in the different environments by means of the "Test" function, both work. But when I try from postman, only work DEV. The only error I see for CloudWatch is the following:

**Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address**.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the name of variables in **Stage Variables**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you are having is that you need to deploy your stage. i.e.

API -> Resources -> Actions (on root of api) -> Deploy Api

Then select the stage you want to deploy get the new endpoint and test from postman.

Comment: Thanks, but i I've done that several times already. Even trying to create new environments and still not working